# cannot update data value via jquery

Tags: jquery

I can't update the data value via jQuery, I found a similar question but it did not help in this case.

I have data called `color` with a value of `red` to start with, and I just want to change the value on page load to green.

```
<div class="test" data-color="red"></div>

if ( $('.test').data('color') === 'red' ) {
    $(this).data('color', 'green');
}
```

Comment: have you put your js code in script tag?

Comment: Is this in a handler of some kind? If not, 'this' isn't going to refer to what you think it will.

Comment: it's look fine to me, i am wondering what error you are getting

Comment: No error. I had an `alert` there inside of the `if` and it did alert. It recognizes the value to be red in the beginning, but will not update it.

Comment: I also tried hardcoding `.test` instead of `this` but it makes no difference.

Comment: did you write code in document.ready or after DOM is loaded ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use the [**attr()**](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) in jquery

```
$(this).attr('data-color', 'green');
```

change the selector too

```
if ( $('.test').attr('data-color') == 'red' ) {
    $('.test').attr('data-color', 'green');
  }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CxNNh/551/)

Comment: It is not working. The code is inside document ready in my script. Is that a problem?

Comment: That IS the problem! But why? The html element exists in normal html, it is not created on the fly.

Comment: @BlekStena check the demo. Click on the div

Comment: @BlekStena did you chek it?

Comment: Hello, I did just now. This works, but on my end it has to be outside `ready`. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

`this` doesnt refer to `.test`, if you want to change the data color value of `.test` element, you need to use :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ( $('.test').data('color') === 'red' ) {
        $('.test').data('color', 'green');
    }
});
```

As you want it to append when page load, make sure that the target element exists when you access the data attribute value

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell from what you've shown, but unless this is in a handler of some kind, your $(this) isn't referring to the element you're selecting when you check it in your if statement. Try this instead:

```
var $test = $('.test');

if ($test.data('color') === 'red') {
    $test.data('color', 'green');
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7epr/) to demonstrate it working.

Comment: You are alerting correct value, but it is not changing data attr actually. İnspect element and see what is there

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL the OP's question is about changing the value on page load, not the attribute value found in the element. Data attributes that appear in elements are to initialize the data for the element, not the attribute. When you change it with jQuery's .data method, it's changing the value, not the attribute, as designed.

Answer (score -1):

```
if ( $('.test').attr("data-color") == 'red' ) {
    $(this).attr({'data-color', 'green'});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do:

```
$.each($('.test'), function() {
    if ( $(this).data('color') === 'red' ) {
        $(this).attr('data-color', 'green');
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6enf5/)**

Answer (score -1):

If you need or want to use that sintax to get, update or create that kind of attributtes, you can make a simple plugin for jquery like this:

```
    (function ($) {
    $.fn.data = function (prop, value) {
        if(value) {
            return $(this).attr('data-' + prop, value);
        }else{
            return $(this).attr('data-' + prop);//Or return $(this).data(prop);
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use `data("key", "value")` operation for updating dom attributes. Because, this function is also for manipulating object properties like `data-custom={"key":"value"}`. When you use `data("color")` this will return an object and will be saved jquery `$.cache`. When you update it, actually it will update cached version, not actual dom property.

You can see [jquery doc](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5);

`The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values are then stored internally in jQuery).`

For updating dom property, you can use [attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) like;

```
if ( $('.test').data('color') === 'red' ) {
    $('.test').attr('data-color', 'green');
}
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/etb6k/